# How to evaluate $ \int \sec^3x \, \mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: integration

How to evaluate $ \int \sec^3x \, \mathrm{d}x$ ?

I tried integration by parts and then I got $$\int \sec^3x \, \mathrm{d}x=\sec x \tan x - \int\sec x \tan^2 x \, \mathrm{d}x.$$ Now I'm stuck solving $\int\sec x \tan^2 x \, \mathrm{d}x$? How to solve that and how to solve my initial question? *What is the smartest way solving $ \int \sec^3x \, \mathrm{d}x$?*

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed

Comment: The *smartest way* to solve the integral is to look it up in an integral table.

Comment: You can solve a lot of integrals like this using the [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution). This one has a relatively easier solution, see below, but this trick is a useful one to know.

Comment: hint: $$\int \sec^3x \, \mathrm{d}x=\sec x \tan x - \int\sec x \tan^2 x \, \mathrm{d}x=\sec x \tan x - \int\sec x (\sec^2 x-1) \, \mathrm{d}x=\dots$$

Answer (score 10):

This is a [well-known problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed). Using $ \left( u, v \right) = \left( \sec x, \tan x \right) $ gives $$ \begin {align*} \displaystyle\int \sec^3  \, \mathrm{d}x &= \displaystyle\int \sec x \tan x - \displaystyle\int \sec x \tan^2 x \, \mathrm{d}x \\&= \sec x \tan x - \displaystyle\int \sec^3 x \, \mathrm{d}x + \displaystyle\int \sec x \, \mathrm{d}x. \end {align*} $$If we let our integral be $I$, then, $ 2I = \sec x \tan x + \displaystyle\int \sec x \, \mathrm{d}x = \sec x \tan x + \ln \left| \sec x + \tan x \right| + \mathcal{C}_0 $, so we have $$ \displaystyle\int \sec^3 x \, \mathrm{d}x = \boxed {\dfrac {\sec x \tan x + \ln \left| \sec x + \tan x \right|}{2} + \mathcal{C}}. $$

Answer (score 8):

Since
$$\sec^3 x = \frac{1}{\cos^3 x}=\frac{\cos x}{\cos^4 x}=\frac{\cos x}{(1-\sin^2 x)^2},$$
we just need a primitive for
$$ f(t) = \frac{1}{(1-t^2)^2} $$
that is:
$$ F(t) = \frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{2t}{1-t^2}+\log\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right).$$

Comment: Probably better to not use $x$ after the substitution, but otherwise nice.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: you're right, fixed.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\int\sec^3 x dx = \sec x \tan x - \int \sec x \tan ^2 x dx
$$
using $\tan^2 x+1 = \sec^2 x$ we find
$$
I = \sec x \tan x - \int \sec x \tan ^2 x dx = \sec x \tan x - \int \sec x \left(\sec^2 x-1\right)dx = \sec x \tan x- I + \int \sec x dx
$$
thus we get
$$
2I = \sec x \tan x + \int \sec x dx
$$
now (an interesting derivation and a lot harder than you think to solve try it yourself)
$$
\int \sec x dx = \ln|\sec x + \tan x| + C
$$
thus
$$
I = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sec x \tan x + \ln|\sec x + \tan x| + C\right)
$$

Answer (score 4):

Here is a straight way you are looking for:

a) Show that $(\sec x)^{\prime \prime }=2\sec ^{3}(x)-\sec x;$

b) Deduce $\int \sec ^{3}x\mathsf{d}x.$

Answer: Recall that $(\sec x)^{\prime }=\sec x\tan x,$ so 
\begin{eqnarray*}
(\sec x)^{\prime \prime } &=&\left( (\sec x)^{\prime }\right) ^{\prime
}=\left( \sec x\tan x\right) ^{\prime }=(\sec x)^{\prime }\tan x+\sec
x\left( \tan x\right) ^{\prime } \\
&=&\sec x\tan x\tan x+\sec x\sec ^{2}x=\sec x(\sec ^{2}x-1)+\sec ^{3}x \\
&=&\sec ^{3}x-\sec x+\sec ^{3}x=2\sec ^{3}(x)-\sec x
\end{eqnarray*}

b) We compute the integral of the second derivative like this
$$
\int (\sec x)^{\prime \prime }\mathsf{d}x=\int (2\sec ^{3}(x)-\sec x)\mathsf{
d}x,
$$
but the integral of a derivative is the function itself! then 
$$
\int (\sec x)^{\prime \prime }\mathsf{d}x=(\sec x)^{\prime }+c=\sec x\tan x+c
$$
therefore
$$
\sec x\tan x+c=2\int \sec ^{3}x\mathsf{d}x-\int \sec x\mathsf{d}x=2\int \sec
^{3}x\mathsf{d}x-\ln (\sec x+\tan x)
$$
from which it follows
$$
\int \sec ^{3}x\mathsf{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\sec x\tan x+\frac{1}{2}\ln (\sec
x+\tan x)+c.
$$

Comment: you can compute in the same way the integral of $csc^3(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Since I mentioned it in comments, there is a general approach to such problems, the [Weierstrass half-angle substitution.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution)

Let $u=\tan \frac{x}{2}$ then $\cos x = \frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}$ and $dx=\frac{2du}{1+u^2}$.

So:

$$\int \sec^3 x \,dx = \int \frac{2(1+u^2)^2du}{(1-u^2)^3}$$

You are still going to need to do a partial fraction decomposition.

It's messy. but this trick is worth knowing because it can be used in so many questions.

Cheating to keep this brief, Wolfram Alpha gives the partial fraction decomposition as:

$$\frac{2(1+u^2)^2}{(1-u^2)^3} = \frac{1}{2(u+1)} -\frac{1}{2(u+1)^2} + \frac{1}{(u+1)^3}  - \frac{1}{2(u-1)} - \frac{1}{2(u-1)^2} - \frac{1}{(u-1)^3} $$